# flatten a BlockMatrix into a Matrix in Sympy

Tags: matrix, sympy

Sympy has `BlockMatrix` class, but it is not a regular `Matrix`,
eg you can not matrix multiply a BlockMatrix.
`BlockMatrix` is a convenient way to build a structured matrix, but I do not see a way to use it with unstructured matrices.
Is there a way to flatten a `BlockMatrix`, or another convenient way to build a regular `Matrix` from blocks, similar to `numpy.blocks`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `as_explicit()` to get a flat explicit matrix, like this:

```
from sympy import *

n = 3
X = Identity(n)
Y = Identity(n)
Z = Identity(n)
W = Identity(n)

R = BlockMatrix([[X,Y],[Z,W]])
print (R.as_explicit())
```